# How can i execute a specific css base on the choices of the user in checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i make this work? I need to run specific css code base on the choices of the user in a checkbox.

Example:

1. Platform = Unix, Windows and Network = Execute the css for Unix, Windows and Network
2. Platform = Windows and Network = Execute the css for Windows and Network

I will be running this in a content editor in sharepoint calendar list.

Please refer to the codes below

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitClicked(){
    var platform = $("input[name='platform']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();    
    var csscode="";
 
    if(platform=="Unix,Windows,Network"){
        csscode="UnixCSS,WindowsCSS,NetworkCSS";
    }
    if(platform=="Unix,Windows"){
        csscode="UnixCSS,WindowsCSS";
    }
    if(platform=="Unix,Network"){
        csscode="UnixCSS,NetworkCSS";
    }
    if(platform=="Unix"){
        csscode="UnixCSS";
    }
    if(platform=="Windows"){
        csscode="WindowsCSS";
    }
    if(platform=="Network"){
        csscode="NetworkCSS";
    }   
}
</script>
```

```css
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//UnixCSS

.ms-acal-color1 div, .ms-acal-color1 div a, .ms-acal-apanel-color1 SPAN {
display: none;
}

.ms-acal-color1{
display: none;
}
 
.ms-acal-selcolor1{
display: none;
}
 
.ms-acal-apanel-color1{
display: none;
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//WindowsCSS

.ms-acal-color2 div, .ms-acal-color2 div a, .ms-acal-apanel-color2 SPAN {
display: none;
}

.ms-acal-color2{
display: none;
}
 
.ms-acal-selcolor2{
display: none;
}
 
.ms-acal-apanel-color2{
display: none;
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//NetworkCSS

.ms-acal-color3 div, .ms-acal-color3 div a, .ms-acal-apanel-color3 SPAN {
display: none;
}

.ms-acal-color3{
display: none;
}
 
.ms-acal-selcolor3{
display: none;
}
 
.ms-acal-apanel-color3{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>Platform</div> 
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Unix">Unix
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Windows">Windows
<input id="platform" checked type="checkbox" name="platform" value="Network">Network<br><br>
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="SubmitClicked()" id="go" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yous should change a tag class according to the checkbox change. [reference](https://codepen.io/richerimage/pen/gbLXJN)

Or you can use `:checked` css pseudo-class. [reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-style-switcher-with-pure-css-using-checked/)

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I just made a few modification.But i referred on your first reference